# Clone div and append value from textarea on submit on multiple forms blocks jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have set of forms, basically is a multi reply boxes, when I am trying to get the value of each reply form and then append it to a container under each form block, I am able to get the value of each and then clone it, and append it to a container, but the problem is my script is not appending the the value to each block, is basically appending to the first block only, I created a http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/NgEpS/

This is my html:
            
                
                    
                        
                        
                    
                    
                    
                        1

```
        <div class="post-container">
            <form class="reply-form">
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <textarea placeholder="Reply box 2..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
                <div class="post-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply hidden"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="post-container">
            <form class="reply-form">
                <div class="reply-box">
                    <textarea placeholder="Reply box 3..." columns="10" rows="1" name="comment-input"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
                <div class="post-dropdown"></div>
                <div class="post-dropdown-content">
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">1</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">2</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">3</div>
                    <div class="post-dropdown-reply">4</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        ​
```

This is my js:

```
        function gettingReplyVal() {

            $('.reply-form').submit(function(e) {
                var post_clone =    $('.post-dropdown-content').first().clone();

                var textAreaValue = $(this).find('textarea').val();

                $(post_clone).insertBefore(".post-dropdown-content:first").find('.post-dropdown-reply').html(textAreaValue);

                e.preventDefault();

            });
        }

        gettingReplyVal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/NgEpS/1/

Changes are on this line:

```
 $(post_clone).insertBefore($(this).find(".post-dropdown-content")).find('.post-dropdown-reply').html(textAreaValue);
```

I changed it to find the .post-dropdown-content div using the $(this) context. Yours was finding the first one on the page.

Comment: Nice, wondering if you have any idea why after replying to all the comment forms once, and doning a second reply on each is now cloning all the child divs? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
// Find the text that was entered
var textAreaValue = $(this).find('textarea').val();

// Make a new post div, and add the appropriate classes
post = $("<div>").addClass("post-dropdown-reply");

// Set its html
post.html(textAreaValue);

// Add it onto the content list
$(this).find('.post-dropdown-content').prepend(post);
```

This has the downside that you have to have to generate a new post div from scratch, but it works much better. (See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SQcn/))